# How can I decode the encoded XML response from my SSO identity provider using Spring 6 and opensaml 4 in Java 17?

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I have a string that i get in request from idp to service provider. I know that this string is encoded xml response, but i do not know how can i decode it

I am trying to update my service provider application to use spring 6, java 17 and opensaml 4. I am using ssocircle as identity provider.

After login I see saml response(xml) and the request to my application using chrome saml extension. The request contains "Request POST Data" section that contains encoded(i think so) response.

Here is it value(not full):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxaDt.png)

But I also see a valid xml (saml response) in saml extension
The problem is that i need to get xml view from request, but all i can do is to use ServletRequest.getInputStream() and get encoded string from request body.

Do you know how can I decode this string and get an xml? May be i can use certificates for that?